# How can I turn the wireless capabilities of an HP Pavilion DV5 on?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

I upgraded my HP Pavilion DV5 from Windows Vista Home Premium to Windows 7 Professional.

Everything is fine, only the wireless is not working at all.

I checked everything, no driver is missing, I troubleshot and the message I got is that the wireless capabilities are off and I can't turn it on from the button in front of the PC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a physical switch that turns the wireless on and off?  If it's at all like my HP then it's a touch button at the top and must be blue instead of red.  Also, you may need to make sure that the drivers for the touch button are installed for them to work properly.

Comment: From OP: "and I can't turn it on from the button in front of the pc."  Sounds like he tried this.

Comment: It's a touch button, I'm sorry and it is red doesn't turn blue since I installed windows 7. Everything is fine in the device manager.no driver is missing.

Comment: @ amon: "it is red doesn't turn blue since I installed windows 7" This leads me to believe that this is your issue.  Even though there is no "problems" with your drivers doesn't mean that the drivers aren't correctly installed.  Windows 7 just installs the generic or certified drivers that are available.  Visit the [HP](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/siteHome?lc=en&dlc=en&cc=us) webiste and look for the proper drivers for the touch pad.

Comment: I'll visit HP website

Answer (score 0):

Does Windows even detect that there is a wireless adapter in the laptop?

Did you install the 64 driver for the adapter?

Is there a switch on the wireless adapter itself?

Is the adapter USB based or PCMCIA? If so, make sure it is plugged in all the way and see if it works on another machine as it may have died.

Comment: Yes, when I opened the properties of my network.

Comment: Did you install the correct driver? I say this because your Vista install may have been x86 and most Windows 7 installs are x64.

Comment: I did not install the 64 bit driver for the adapter, there is no switch but touch button. It's a built-in card.

Comment: vista was x64 and windows 7 is x86

Comment: Since you installed the x86 driver for it, did you get the drivers from HP's website for Windows 7 or Vista? Reason I am saying this is because some manufacturers only offer the Vista drivers even though they are most likely compatible with Windows 7.